# How to download the json content using python

Tags: python, json

```
import json
path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/datasets/bitly_usagov/example.txt'
store = [json.loads(line), for line in open(path)]
store[0]
```

The above code isn't working. I want to see the records stored in store

Comment: What error you are getting while running this code...

Comment: You need to retrieve the URL's contents.  Your code does not do that.  You want `urllib`, `requests`, or something similar to retrieve the URL contents and then parse THAT.

Comment: remove comma from comprehension

Comment: use requests library to pull data from url

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 
import json 
response = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/datasets/bitly_usagov/example.txt')
with open('pakka.txt', mode = 'wb') as file:
 file.write(response.content)

f = 'pakka.txt'
records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(f)]
records[0]
```

Hi guys - This code worked for me. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

you can also try this one

```
    import urllib.request
    resource = urllib.request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/datasets/bitly_usagov/example.txt')
    content =  resource.read().decode(resource.headers.get_content_charset())
```

Comment: import requests
import json

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples
r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/datasets/bitly_usagov/example.txt')
print(r)